# Python combine two excel sheets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, python-3.7

I have 2 excel sheets
1st excel workbook has id,firstname,lastname,workemail , location.
2nd excel work book has 
id, email address,country.
I need to combine the data from two sheets and have the o/p as
sheet1: Customerid,firstname,lastname,workemail ,location. 
sheet2: Customerid,                     email address,country.

o/p: The customer id from both sheet should be concatinated and workemail and emailaddress and location and country should be concatinated.

The above Customerid Type is not unique. 
The sheet1 has values :"ExistingCustomer",
The sheet2 has values : "New Customer:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  We really need to have more information and a better formatted question in order to help you.  For instance, you might show us a snippet of the first 5 rows of the first and second excels workbooks.

Comment: Maybe you have misuderstood, but StackOverflow is not for asking others to implement something for you. You need to try to do it yourself first, and I'm sure people will help you if you have issues, but for that, you need to include what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read both sheets into separate pandas dataframes and try concatenate them together. Hope this helps

[Merge, join, and concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: I have tried those but i am unable to fetch the o/p as required. I will reiterate my question and post the question clearly.